# Multiple Version of libstdc++ in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, libstdc++, linaro

I am having a Raspberry Pi 3.
I have installed its native tool-chain on my `Raspberry Pi 3 : GCC 4.9.2` (`Raspbian 4.9.2-10`) and necessary run-time libraries.
I have downloaed `gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_armv8l-linux-gnueabihf : gcc version 6.3.1 20170404 (Linaro GCC 6.3-2017.05)`  and  installed it on my desktop and have even downloaded necessary run-times and copied them on my `Raspberry Pi 3`.
I have copied necessary run-time library in `/usr/lib/armv8l-linux-gnueabihf/` and `/lib/armv8l-linux-gnueabihf/ folders`.

I am facing the same issue even if I am using Linario GCC 4.9.2 instead of Linario 6.3.1

I get the following error :

> ./gatewaycomminication: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6:
>       version CXXABI_1.3.9 not found (required by ./gatewaycomminication)
>
> ./gatewaycomminication: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6:
>   version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by
>
> ./gatewaycomminication) ./gatewaycomminication:
>   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
>   not found (required by ./gatewaycomminication)

If I enable static build the program runs properly.
I have tried the following possible solutions (but none seem to work) :

1. `-Wl,-rpath,-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/armv8l-linux-gnueabihf`
2. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/armv8l-linux-gnueabihf:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
3. `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/armv8l-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib/armv8l-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22`
4. `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/armv8l-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 gatewayCommunication`

Kindly advice how can I get my program compiled in `Linario GCC 6.3` start working in `Raspberry Pi 3` using shared library model.

Comment: I am facing the same issue even if I am using Linario GCC 4.9.2